# Swift 4: "filter.count" vs "for loop with where", why 'filter.count' is faster?

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop

I'm testing on Swift collection here is the code:

```
func printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(title:String, operation:()->())
{
  let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
  operation()
  let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
  print("Time elapsed for \(title): \(timeElapsed) s.")
}

extension Sequence
{
  func count(where predicate: (Element) -> Bool) -> Int
  {
    return filter(predicate).count
  }

  func count2(where predicate: (Element) -> Bool) -> Int
  {
    var c: Int = 0
    for element in self where predicate(element)
    {
      c += 1
    }
    return c
  }

  func count3(where predicate: (Element) -> Bool) -> Int
  {
    return reduce(into: 0) { if predicate($1) { $0 += 1 } }
  }
}

let ccc = 1...1000000

printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(title: "count Test") {
  let _ = ccc.count(where: { $0 % 2 == 0 })
}

printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(title: "count Test 2") {
  let _ = ccc.count2(where: { $0 % 2 == 0 })
}

printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(title: "count Test 3") {
  let _ = ccc.count3(where: { $0 % 2 == 0 })
}
```

This code prints

```
 Time elapsed for count Test: 18.0662090778351 s. 
 Time elapsed for count Test 2 : 28.3750340938568 s.
```

As you can see the first count function is faster than the second. Anyone knows why?

Edit:

Thank you all, I've modified the code as suggested, these are the new results using Xcode with aggressive optimization:

```
Time elapsed for count Test: 51.4916070699692 s.
Time elapsed for count Test 2: 51.3513959646225 s.
Time elapsed for count Test 3: 50.2809948921204 s.
```

results using Xcode with Fastest/Smallest optimisation

```
Time elapsed for count Test: 51.5341190099716 s.
Time elapsed for count Test 2: 51.3876320123672 s.
Time elapsed for count Test 3: 50.2216899394989 s.
```

These are the result using the Swift compiler `swiftc -o`

```
Time elapsed for count Test: 52.560210943222 s
Time elapsed for count Test 2: 51.3171380758286 s.
Time elapsed for count Test 3: 51.3849959373474 s.
```

So, it appears that filter is surely less efficient than the for loop and the reduce function. 
It also appears that the reduce function may be faster than the for loop, any idea for this evidence?

Comment: Are you testing on a compiled app with optimizations turned on or are you testing in a playground? Never test speed in a playground.

Comment: @maddy I'm testing on a macOS playground

Comment: That's no good. Test in a compiled command line app with optimizations turned on. Then update your question based on the new, proper results.

Comment: `filter(predicate)` creates a new array. The other method does not. In my test (compiled project in Release mode) the second method is *much* faster.

Comment: @AR89 count3 `return reduce(into: 0) { if predicate($1) { $0 += 1 } }`

Comment: Note that Swift 5 will have a `count(where:)` method. See https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0220-count-where.md, which also contains a reference implementation.

Comment: @LeoDabus I have runned some test with your version, seem faster on the Xcode project, any idea why?

Comment: Do. Not. Benchmark. In. Playground! Make a command-line app and run the code through a profiler. You'll be surprised how small the differences become due to optimizations.